# How to use IFileInfo to delete a file in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have read that it's better I use `IFileProvider` for managing files in ASP.NET Core [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.1). but, if I use `GetFileInfo()` method I will have access to `IFileInfo` and it just provides some methods for reading files!

How can I delete a file?

Comment: The docs never say that IFileProvder is used to manage files, much less that it's better than the System.IO classes, that already abstract the file system. [They say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.1#file-provider-interfaces) that IFileProvider is used to abstact access and provide file, directory info and change notifications.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your comment, do you think is it OK to use System.IO in the .Net Core?

Comment: What files do you want to delete? Why not use `File.Delete` or `FileInfo.Delete` as always? The System.IO classes aren't NTFS-specific, they end up using each operating system's file system APIs. Do you worry about path differences in Linux vs Windows perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as you mentioned I'm worried about a different path in the OS like Linux, Windows and ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've suggested in comments that your concern is the different form of *paths* in different Operating Systems that your code may be running on. As long as you don't try to `string.Concat` or `+` bits of your paths together, build them up in a StringBuilder or in any other way try to pretend that you'll be able to build a valid path yourself in any circumstances you'll be fine :). The filesystem related classes in the `System.IO` namespace are there specifically to help you to get this right, so do use them.

If you've already got an instance of `IFileProvider` from somewhere else (say that's what you're using the enumerate the files to *display* to users so they can choose which ones to delete), you can mix-and-match that with `System.IO`, perhaps with something like this:

```
public void SomeMethodThatsCalled()
{
    // I'm presuming there's a lot of other code here, and that the IFileProvider
    // is actually dependency injected somewhere, somehow, but it's self-contained
    // here for completeness
    IFileProvider physicalFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"D:\DeleteMyContentsPlease\");

    DeleteFiles(physicalFileProvider);
}

private void DeleteFiles(IFileProvider physicalFileProvider)
{
    if (physicalFileProvider is PhysicalFileProvider)
    {
        var directory = physicalFileProvider.GetDirectoryContents(string.Empty);
        foreach (var file in directory)
        {
            if (!file.IsDirectory)
            {
                var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(file.PhysicalPath);
                fileInfo.Delete();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**There's absolutely no error-checking, validation, exception handling or anything else that would remotely make this production code present here** (with the *possible* exception of actually checking that the entry in the directory isn't a directory!) so please don't use it as-is.

*Equally:* If you've not got an instance of `IFileSystem` from anywhere, don't feel particularly obliged to create one just to delete files!